# Get all replies to post in NewsFeed

Tags: sharepoint-designer, designer-workflow, newsfeed

I have a workflow that sends an email to users when a new post gets added to a newsfeed. From looking at the MicroFeed list I can see that column `MicroBlogType` contain a `2` for posts and a `4` for replies.

Is there a way to tell from the MicroFeed list which replies belong to which posts?